# V-menu unable to scroll down to view other list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

May I what happen to my v-menu list, it unable to scroll down to view other category.
I have checked my code and it's no problem before that.
May I know is the vuetify version issue that causes the code syntax have been deprecated?

[image]

My vue code here:

```
<span v-if="invalid.category" style="color:red;">*{{invalid.category}}</span>
      <v-layout class="category-box">
          <div class="category-title">
              <h3>{{$translate('category')}}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="category-link">
              <template v-for="(c,i) in categoryLink">
                  <v-btn slot="activator" flat color="blue darken-4" :dark="catInfo(c).isFinal==1" 
                   @click="killChild(i)">
                      {{$translate(catInfo(c).cat_title)}}
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-icon v-if="catInfo(c).isFinal==0">chevron_right</v-icon>
              </template>
              <v-menu overflow: auto v-if="choices.length>0">
                  <v-btn slot="activator" color="primary" dark>
                      -
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-list>
                      <v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in choices" :key="index" 
                      @click="nextChoice(item.value)">
                          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
                      </v-list-tile>
                  </v-list>
              </v-menu>
          </div>
      </v-layout>
```

My scripts here:

```
<script>
    export default {
          data(){
         return {
          loading: false,
          product: null,
          countries: null,
          categories: null,
          choices: [],
          categoryLink: [],


       variationTable:{
          headers:[

          ],
          items: [

          ],
        },
       variant:{
          attribute: {},
          enableVariation: false,
          enableVariation2: false,
      },

      invalid: {},
    }
  },
     created(){
        this.getProduct()
  },
     methods:{
      getProduct() {
        var self = this
        var pid = this.$route.params.pid
        this.loading = true
        axios.get('/api/merchant/product/productDetail?pid=' + pid)
        .then(response => {
            self.generateForm(response.data.product,response.data.categories,response.data.countries)
            self.loading = false
        })
      },
      generateForm(product,categories,countries){
            this.product = product
            this.setCategory(categories)
            this.setCountry(countries)
            this.setVariantTable(product.variant)

      if(this.product.productImage == null){
           this.product.productImage = [];
      }else{
           this.product.productImage = this.product.productImage.split(",");
      }

        // Product Banner
        if(this.product.productBanner == null){
         this.product.productBanner = [];
        }else{
         this.product.productBanner = this.product.productBanner.split(",");
        }
      },
    setCategory(categories) {
    this.categories = categories
    var next = this.product.category_id
    while (next != 0) {
        var cat = this.catInfo(next)
        this.categoryLink.push(cat.category_id)
        next = cat.cat_parent
    }

    if (this.categoryLink.length > 0) {
        var last = this.categoryLink[0]
        this.categoryLink = this.categoryLink.reverse()
    } else {
        this.nextChoice()
    }

},
setCountry(countries) {
    this.countries = []
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var name = countries[i].country_name.toLowerCase()
        this.countries.push({
            'title': countries[i].country_name,
            'currency': countries[i].currency_id,
            'fee': parseFloat(this.product["to_" + name]) >= 0 ? parseFloat(this.product["to_" + name]) : 0,
            'checked': parseFloat(this.product["to_" + name]) >= 0 ? true : false,
            'var': "to_" + name
        })
    }
},
setVariantTable(variant){
    if(variant == null)
        return ;

    variant = JSON.parse(variant);

    this.variant.attribute = variant.attribute;
    variant = variant.variant;

    for(let j=1;j<4;j++){
        if(this.variant.attribute['A'+ j] != null){
            if(j >= 2) this.variant.enableVariation2 = true;

            this.variationTable['headers'].push({
                text: this.variant.attribute['A' + j],
                value: 'A' + j,
                sortable: false
            })
        }
    }

    this.variationTable['headers'].push({
                text: this.$translate('price'),
                value: 'Price',
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                text: this.$translate('stock'),
                value: 'Stock',
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                text: this.$translate('sku'),
                value: 'SKU',
                sortable: false
            })

    for(let i=0; i<variant.length; i++){
        this.variationTable['items'].push(variant[i])
    }
},
nextChoice(sel = 0) {
    var c = this.categories.filter(function(cat) {
        return cat.cat_parent == sel
    })
    this.choices = []
    if (c.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            this.choices.push({
                text: this.$translate(c[i].cat_title),
                value: c[i].category_id
            })
        }
    } else {
        this.product.category_id = sel
    }

    if (sel > 0) {
        this.categoryLink.push(sel)
    }
},
killChild(i) {
    this.nextChoice(this.categoryLink[i - 1])
    this.categoryLink.length = i
},
catInfo(id) {
    try {
        var result = this.categories.filter(function(cat) {
            return cat.category_id == id
        })[0]
    } catch (e) {
        var result = {}
    }

    return result
   }
  }
 }
 </script>
```

My expected result able to scroll down to choose other category.
I have no idea what's happen with the vuetify code, maybe is vuetify version?
Anyone would help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `max-height` prop of your `v-menu` - otherwise it will not show a scrollbar.

Comment: is written like max-height: auto?

Comment: Should be `max-height="90vh"`